# Eclipse shows errors even though maven build succeeds

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I have eclipse 4.10, with m2eclipse plugin. I can build my project perfectly using Maven, either through command line or through [right click] -> run -> maven install.

But annoyingly, eclipse still complains that some files have compilation errors. They seem to refer to different versions from desired. This makes me worried that if I run my program from command line, I might not be running the build I desire.

How do I solve this problem? Thank you!

[UPDATE: Thanks for the reply, but Project->clean and [right click]->run->maven clean don't work either...

Comment: This seems to be an Eclipse caching problem. I would try "Project->Clean..." and then "Maven->Update Project...". If this doesn't work I would try an Eclipse re-start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `mvn clean eclipse:eclipse` solved the problem! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Do a right click on your project then `maven->update project` will work for you